# Mex doesn't recognize type 'Matrix'

Tags: linux, matlab, types, mex, cc

I'm trying to create a mex file for a c function which is supposed to be a Matlab interface for Chaco http://www.cerfacs.fr/algor/Softs/MESHPART/ (Chaco is a graph partitioning software).

I modified the Makefile quite a bit to make it work with my Debian. However, there is one error which I can't solve. when I run the mex command
`mex -output mlchaco ${mlfiles.c} chaco.a  -I chaco/main`

I get the following error:

`mlchaco.c:55:5: error: unknown type name 'Matrix'`

chaco.a option in my mex command line is:

`chaco.a:   ${CHFILES.o}
            ${AR} chaco.a ${CHFILES.o} ; ${RANLIB} chaco.a`

and the first few lines of the c code which cause the error are

`void mexFunction(

    int         nlhs,           /* number of expected outputs */
    Matrix      *plhs[],        /* matrix pointer array returning outputs */
    int         nrhs,           /* number of inputs */
    Matrix      *prhs[]         /* matrix pointer array for inputs */
    )`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Matrix` with `mxArray`, the type passed by MATLAB.  Be sure to `include "mex.h"`.